# How can I use two API Key to authorize two graphql fields separately in Appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am using Appsync as graphql server. I have read through this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/ which allows me to use multiple authorisation methods in graphql.

I have two fields on graphql schema which require API Key authorization. Can I assign one key for one field and a different key for different field?

By looking at the `@aws_api_key`, it doesn't have extra parameter like `name` or something. It seems that if a field is authorized by API_KEY, it can be accessed by any API KEY generated by the appsync.

Can I create one APIKEY for a particular field? I am looking for something like below schema:

```
getAllPosts(): [Post]
    @aws_api_key(key1)


updatePost(post: Post): Post
    @aws_api_key(key2)
```

I'd like to use `key1` for `getAllPosts` and `key2` for `updatePost`. How can I achieve this in appsync?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't use multiple API keys on a single API. However you can configure multiple user pools if you use Amazon Cognito.

Comment: I see I can configure multiple user pools. But how can I declare each pool in `@ aws_cognito_user_pools` directive in the schema? Does it accept any other parameter like user pool id? I can't find anything for me to do that.

Comment: I just found that I can't connect multiple user pools to Appsync